# GET PHP MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal, estou com uma dúvida.
Eu tenho uma página de `udpate` que utiliza o `$_GET` para pegar a url, porém no form de update eu joguei o action em outra pasta, ai na hora de fazer o update não reconhece o ID, pois saiu da página atual, como eu posso resolver isso, visto que deu problema colocando o código na mesma página do form, pois atualizava apenas eu clicando no botão sem preencher. e também para organização do código, segue código do update

```
$ID        = isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : '';
$titulo    = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo'] : '';
$descricao = isset($_POST['descricao']) ? $_POST['descricao'] : '';
$alt       = isset($_POST['alt']) ? $_POST['alt'] : '';

$bd->query("UPDATE tortas SET titulo = '$titulo', descricao = '$descricao', alt = '$alt' WHERE ID = '$ID'");
```

Comment: Você pode passar o ID em um input do tipo hidden, assim você vai conseguir pegar ele na outra página utilizando a variavel global `$_POST['id']`

Comment: No ficheiro PHP que tem o form, tens de mandar os dados para o novo PHP onde tens a instrução SQL, faço me entender?

Comment: Deixa na mesma página do form e coloca o UPDATE dentro de um `if` verificando se as variáveis estão cheias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
// Página 1 - Onde tem o formulário
// Vamos supor que a URL é: http://localhost/noticia/editar?id=15

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="titulo" />
<input type="text" name="descricao" />
```

```
// Página 2 - Onde vai atualizar

$ID        = $_POST['ID'];
$titulo    = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo'] : '';
$descricao = isset($_POST['descricao']) ? $_POST['descricao'] : '';
$alt       = isset($_POST['alt']) ? $_POST['alt'] : '';

// O ideal seria você validar se o ID foi informado
if ($ID !== null) {
    // Tratar erro...
}

$bd->query("UPDATE tortas SET titulo = '$titulo', descricao = '$descricao', alt = '$alt' WHERE ID = '$ID'");
```